# What tools can be used to coordinate work in a web development project?

Tags: svn

I have no domain experience, but I want to start a web project involving some of my friends (who've created websites before). (tech used: PHP, HTML, SQL, jQuery, some APIs)

The problem is I need a tool that can coordinate our work (something like SVN) and perhaps it would be nice if we could see the changes on our site after each change.

edit: is this OK? http://www.hochmanconsultants.com/articles/subversion.shtml

edit #2: my concern is: is there a tool generally used by web developers? if not, what's the "best" tool I can use?

edit #3: thank you, guys, your answers really helped! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion is a nice tool, it is a *File Versioning System* that allow you to work with your team in the same project and keep track of every change you made to the files. subversion or other similar software (Git, Mercurial...) is necesary, but you are going to need something else.

I recommend you to try [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) is a free (written on rails) *Project Management System*, this allows you and your co-workers to keep the work organized, control times, discuss in the forums, create a wiki about the project and integrate with subversion, to review the code changes.

Among this you will need some development tools for the technologies you choose.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

for sure you need a versioning tool like SVN or GIT (you can have a free git repository on github.com).

Also I would consider to use a project management / bug-tracking tool like Trac
or Redmine.

Answer (score 0):

Our team uses Mercurial for both web apps and iPhone apps.  It's a distributed version control system.  Git is similar and very popular as well.  Personally, been very happy with Mercurial.